# Problems with the currentTime attribute of HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video

I ran into a problem with the currentTime attribute of HTML5 video. My little programm serves different videos (different resolutions) depending on device resolution. I want to check the device resolution after every window.onload, window.resize and window.orientationchange-Event. After those Events it's possible that a new video is served (with a different more appropriate resolution). I don't want to start the video at second 0 again and therefore I tried to capture the currentTime of the video right before the event. My solution works well in IE 10. But all other browsers fail...I don't know why..

Please don't be mean...i'm very new to all of this web stuff and I honestly try my best.

Hope anyone of you can help me...

Here's my code:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-    scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <video id=videoPlayer controls="controls"> </video>


<script>

var pixelRatio = 1.0;
var availScreenWidth;
var availScreenHeight;
var videoResolution;
var type;
var video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
var pos;

window.onload = updateVideo;
window.orientationchange = updateVideo;
window.onresize = updateVideo;

function updateVideo(){   

    pos = video.currentTime;

    updateResolution();

    if(availScreenWidth <800){
        videoResolution = '640x360';
    }
    if(availScreenWidth >=800 && availScreenWidth < 1137){
        videoResolution = '960x540';
    }
    if(availScreenWidth >=1137 && availScreenWidth < 1367){
        videoResolution = '1280x720';
    }
    if(availScreenWidth >=1367 && availScreenWidth < 1681){
        videoResolution = '1600x900';
    }
    if(availScreenWidth >= 1681){
        videoResolution = '1920x1080';
    }

    if (video.canPlayType("video/webm") == 'maybe' || video.canPlayType("video/webm") == 'probably') {
        type = '.webm';
    }
    else if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4") == 'maybe' || video.canPlayType("video/mp4") == 'probably') {
        type = '.mp4';
    }

   video.src = videoResolution + type;

    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        video.currentTime = pos;
        video.play();}, false);

    }

    video.load();


function updateResolution(){

    if (window.devicePixelRatio){
        pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
    availScreenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth * pixelRatio;
    availScreenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight * pixelRatio;

}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `video.load()` is outside of `updateVideo()` - it's hard to see that as the tabs are a bit uneven. So when your update event happens, the source of the video may not actually be updated. Try putting that call inside that event handler function.

However, once you get it working, you may find yourself experiencing a lot of interruptions and more updates than you want. I experimented with a similar situation and found it helped to throttle resize updates. When the function finishes, save the timestamp. The next time you get a resize event, if it's been less than 100ms-300ms or so, set a timeout return early. (Make sure to clear any outstanding timeouts as well.) That way you won't have to update so many times when a user drags the window size.

Comment: Hey...thanks for your advice. I actually paid attention to the resize event fireing multiple times while a user drags the window size. I solved this by using setTimeout(). I just didn't post this here to make the code a bit clearer. The video.load() thing is a copy paste error (shame on me). Actually I completely deleted this call. If I put this call into the event handler function it seems so cause an endless loop: loading...waiting for loadedmetadata....loading...waiting for loadedmetadata....